# Java Comparing three generic elements

Tags: java, sorting, comparison

I want to compare a collection (ArrayList) of elements if they are the same type. In the beginning I do not know what type the elements are (generic types), so I decided to use Object type. But I still cannot compare them. The problem is in the function `triplesort()`.
The warning is:
`Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Object', 'java.lang.Object'.`
 If you have any possible solutions to that problem and you let me know, I would be grateful. <3
Triple.java

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Triple<T, S, U> {
    private T t;
    private S s;
    private U u;
    private ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Triple(T t, S s, U u) {
        setT(t);
        setS(s);
        setU(u);
        array.add(this.t);
        array.add(this.s);
        array.add(this.u);
    }

    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void setS(S s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void setU(U u) {
        this.u = u;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return t;
    }

    public S getSecond() {
        return s;
    }

    public U getThird() {
        return u;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return t + "\n" + s + "\n" + u + "\n";
    }

    public boolean isHomogeneous() {
        return t.getClass() == s.getClass() && t.getClass() == u.getClass();
    }

    public void tripleSort() {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); ++i) {
                Object key = array.get(i);
                int j = i - 1;
                while (j > -1 && array.get(i) > key) {
                    array.set(j + 1, array.get(j));
                    j--;
                }
                array.set(j + 1, key);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only compare primitives with those operators. Are these objects ```Comparable``` ?

Comment: Since an Object is *anything at all*, what could it mean to ask whether something is "greater than" it?

Comment: Actually you can ignore my question . You can only compare objects of the *same* type

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues with code you've provided:

- Relational operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` can be used **only** to compare *numeric primitive* types. Obviously, you can use it with objects.
- To compare reference types you can use [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparingLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)) or these objects can implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (*i.e. they basically are aware how to compare themselves*). **But** it doesn't make since to compare `BigDecimal` and `Boolean`, or `String` and `HashMap`, how would you approach that? For that reason, these interfaces are generic and `Comparator<T>` can't be used with objects of type `U`.

That said, your `Triple<T, S, U>` would not be able to do a lot with these objects belonging to different type (definitely you can't sort them).

Hence, if you need a *data-carrier* holding references of three distinct types, that fine. It's still can be useful, but don't expect from it much.

A [Java 16 record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) fits in this role perfectly well:

```
public record Triple<T, S, U>(T first, S second, U third) {}
```

But if you need to able to operate with these values comparing them with one another then consider changing the `Triple` to hold only elements of type `T`.

Here's an example of how it might be implemented:

```
public static class Triple<T> {
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(3);
    private Comparator<T> comp;
    
    private Triple(T first, T second, T third, Comparator<T> comp) { // no way and no need to invoke this constructor outside the class
        this.comp = comp;
        Collections.addAll(list, first, second, third);
    }
    
    public static <T> Triple<T> getInstance(T first, T second, T third, Comparator<T> comp) {
        Triple<T> triple = new Triple<>(first, second, third, comp);
        triple.init();
        return triple;
    }
    
    public void init() {
        list.sort(comp);
    }
    
    public T getFirst() {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    
    public T getSecond() {
        return list.get(1);
    }
    
    public T getThird() {
        return list.get(2);
    }

    public boolean isHomogeneous() {
        return comp.compare(getFirst(), getSecond()) == 0
            && comp.compare(getFirst(), getThird()) == 0
            && comp.compare(getSecond(), getThird()) == 0;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return list.stream().map(T::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

*Usage example:*

Let's consider a `Triple` storing integer value in Descending order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Triple<Integer> intTriple = Triple.getInstance(5, 3, 12, Comparator.reverseOrder());

    System.out.println(intTriple);
}
```

*Output:*

```
12
5
3
```